# Exclude zeros in a column when calculating mean using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```py
Trip_ID Trip_Trajectory Trip_Distance Trip_Speed
1001    1                15            2
1001    2                10            0
1001    3                20            6
```

I would like to aggregate the data using Groupby. I am getting this result:

```py
Trip_ID Trip_Distance Trip_Speed
1001    45            2,67
```

This is the code that I am using now:

```py
dataset_agg = dataset.groupby('Trip_ID').agg({'Trip_Distance': ['sum'], 'Trip_Speed': ['mean']})
```

But what I need is to exclude zeros in 'Trip_Speed' column to get the following result:

```py
Trip_ID Trip_Distance Trip_Speed
1001    45            4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace zeros with NaN, NaNs are ignored during aggregation.

```
(df.replace(0, np.nan)
   .groupby('Trip_ID', as_index=False)
   .agg({'Trip_Distance': 'sum', 'Trip_Speed': 'mean'}))

   Trip_ID  Trip_Distance  Trip_Speed
0     1001             45         4.0
```